# How can I access the translation part of a skinned Model object's bone transformation?

Tags: xna, c#

I have an animated `Model`, which I process with the `SkinnedEffectProcessor`.
How I can access translations of that model during animation?

It's always a `BoneTransform` I am working with, but I'd like to know which X, Y and Z values are currently changing.

So, during the update I added this line

```
Debug.WriteLine(_model.GetBoneTransform("RootNode").Translation.ToString());
```

but all it outputs is

```
{X:0 Y:0 Z:0}
```

when I trigger the jump-animation. I'm expecting the Y value to go up, since the model is jumping in that animation.

Comment: Your jump animation may not necessarily change the root node position. It all depends on how your model was setup in the 3d modeling application. For instance, the node whose position is actually animated may not even be the actual root node when exported.

Comment: I agree with what @AaronKabashi said. Load the model in an animation or modelling package and watch the root node during the anim to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

The transforms are stored in the bone transformation matrix, and you should be able to extract them via:

```
model.GetBoneTransform("NodeName").Translation
```

However, as noted, they might not be the values you *expect*, because it's possible your animation was exported in such a way that the root node does not animate and all other nodes that are its children do.